# PostGIS: Ordering by the sum of two distances

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have an SQL statement that selects possible bus routes between two points, ordered by the walking distance required from the start point to the departure bus stop (distance1) and the arrival bus stop to destination (distance2).

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT route_id,
          st_distance(journey_points,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint('-4.1425658', '50.3712659'),4326)) AS distance1,
          st_distance(journey_points,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint('-2.2447445', '53.4791466'),4326)) AS distance2
   FROM route
   WHERE ST_DWithin(journey_points, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint('-4.1425658', '50.3712659'),4326), '3.638751848588139')
     AND ST_DWithin(journey_points, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint('-2.2447445', '53.4791466'),4326), '3.638751848588139')) r
ORDER BY distance1+distance2 LIMIT 300
```

This works great for short distances as the ST_DWithin limits it to only a few possible routes but over long distances it is very slow. I would like to be able to use <-> to order by but it only does bounding boxes and I need it to be the sum of both distance1 and distance2. Is there any way to speed up this SQL, maybe taking advantage of indexes?

Comment: You realize your measurements are in degrees right? and also ST_MakePoint doesn't take text, it takes floats, so your wrapping in '' is unnecessary

Comment: Yes, the journey_points is set to SRID 4326 as well so I can compare it to lat/lon coords. The distance measurement in meters is done in server side code.

Comment: Ditch the subquery, it's doing nothing for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Paul. The subquery is there so I can retrieve distance1 and distance2 and then order by their sum. If I remove the subquery I get `column "distance1" does not exist` in `order by`. I could move the sum of the `st_distance()` calculations to `order by`, but then I can't get the value of distance1 and distance2 and the query time is the same. Any other suggestions are most welcome though.

Comment: A few questions:
1. What needs to be dynamic in your query? Do you know all sets of A & B in advance? 
2. Other ways to limit your solution search space. Have you tried nearest neighbour searches? You could find the nearest X routes to A, and the nearest X routes to B, and then sum(distance1,distance2) for the routes you find.

Comment: @raphael  1.The start and end points come from the user and are passed as parameters into the query, so I know what they are before running the query but point A and B could be anywhere in the country.

Comment: 2.I was thinking of that too, specifically selecting the nearest 200 bus stops to point A & B and filtering routes that stop on both sets. However on journeys with multiple legs there are likely to be routes where either/both bus depart/arrive points are further away than the first 200 stops.

Comment: Also I should have mentioned that `journey_points` is a multipoint representing all the stops on that route, so using `<->` with `order by` orders the routes by the distance to the center of it's bounding box rather than the nearest point which is what st_distance does (I think?). However there is a table with references to all the bus stop points for each route so I can `inner join` these in a nearest neighbour search but we're then talking millions of rows on average.

Comment: I honestly think this is just not something PostGIS is designed to do. It sounds like you need something like an instance of a shortest path finder with the bus routes having 0 cost and the only link cost being the walking distance from route to origin/destination.

Comment: I think you're probably right. It's a shame as it does work quite well for short journeys (<20 miles) but when it comes to journeys with multiple transfers it becomes too slow. I'm thinking of rewriting it using C and loading everything into memory using libspatial.